# How to specify manifest when using javac in ANT

Tags: ant, manifest, javac

I have a jar, including the manifest pointing a bunch of jars. I was trying to use javac in ANT to compile the source files. The problem is how to let ANT know this jar is just a manifest, so that it can find the correct the jars by following this manifest. JAVAC doesn't provide an option "manifest" as JAR does.
Any suggestion?

Comment: sorry can you clarify a bit more?

You say: The problem is how to let ANT know this jar is just a manifest, so that it can find the correct the jars by following this manifest.

Comment: I'm not sure if what you want is to use a manifest in Ant, if that's the case look into this http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/manifest.html

Comment: Thanks M.Octavio. For example, I want to use  
    <javac srcdir="${src}"
         destdir="${build}"
         classpath="xyz.jar"
         debug="on"
         source="1.4"
  />

And the source files (say, 1, 2, 3) depend on some jars (say, A, B, C). I have made a jar (say D), which has a manifest pointing to A, B, C. If I specify classpass in javac to be D, ANT actually can't find the necessary packages in A B and C for 1, 2 and 3. How can I do so that ANT can actually go to A B and C to look for necessary packages

Comment: ok why dont you improve you´re question with a bit more of details and let us know http://whathaveyoutried.com/ so we all could help.